# How to make http POST request to access a web service?

Tags: xml, wcf, app-config

How can I use HTTP POST to access the service?
Now the request is by default using HTTP GET , 
but now i will have to change it to POST , how can I achieve 
this? Should I make any changes to app.config file?
I am using .net c# 4.0.

```
ServiceReference2.ServicePortTypeClient svc = new ServiceReference2.ServicePortTypeClient();

//some code
try
{
    ServiceReference2.ResponseType res = svc.getData(part);
    Console.WriteLine(res);

}
catch (Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("not authenticated");
}
```

Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="WebServiceUrl" value="http://vissvc-test.e.intra.net/SvcNative/VisService"/>     
<add key="LogoutUrl" value="http://login.e.intra.net/internal/logout"/>
</appSettings>
<system.net>
<defaultProxy>
<proxy autoDetect="True"/>
</defaultProxy>
</system.net>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true"/>
<webServices>      
  <soapExtensionTypes>
    <add type="SoapExtension, MyExtension"/>
  </soapExtensionTypes>
 </webServices>
 </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>      
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="SoapBinding">
      <customTextMessageEncoding encoding="UTF-8" messageVersion="Soap11"/>
      <httpTransport/>          
    </binding>        
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
   <--! some behavior ---!>
  </behaviorExtensions>
  <bindingElementExtensions>
    <---some behavior extension-->
  </bindingElementExtensions>
</extensions>
<behaviors>      
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Behaviour">         
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://vissvc- test.e.intra.net/SvcNative/VisService "binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="SoapBinding" contract="ServiceReference2.ServicePortType" name="VisService" behaviorConfiguration="Behaviour"/>
</client>    
</system.serviceModel>     
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>     
</configuration>
```

Comment: How is your server configured? Show us some code so we can try to help you.

Comment: @BartBeyers-I have edited to add the code.

Comment: @roopinin I can see no code :(

Comment: @FaizanMubasher- I added the client side code.